# Create an array of selected rows using checkboxes in React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui

I have a table of data. The first column is a Checkbox. I'm trying to create an array of each row id that gets selected.

```
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);
```

---

```
  const handleCheckbox = (event, row) => {
    if (event.target.checked === true) {
      selectedRows.push(row.id);
    } else {
      selectedRows.pop(row.id);
    }
  };
```

---

```
        <TableBody>
            {expenseTransactions.map((row) => (
              <TableRow key={row.id}>
                <TableCell>
                  <Checkbox onChange={(event) => handleCheckbox(event, row)} />
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
       </TableBody>
```

I can't get it to work properly. Any ideas on the best way to handle the onChange event so I have an array of all selected elements, and then if i unselect one, that id would get removed from the array.

Thanks a tonne,

Answer (score 1):

You should not change the `state` directly by using `selectedRows.push()`. The right way is using `setSelectedRows`. The proper code will look like this.

```
const handleCheckbox = (event, row) => {
  if (event.target.checked === true) {
    setSelectedRows([
       ...selectedRows,
       row
    ])
  } else {
    const nextSelectedRows = selectedRows.filter(selectedRow => selectedRow.id != row.id);
    setSelectedRows(nextSelectedRows)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I deal with that scenario I prefer to store the checked elements into an object, using that approach you avoid finding the index affected. Moreover, the Material UI's *Checkbox* has to be set with its *checked* prop.

e.g:

```
 const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState({});
```

the handler:

```
 const handleCheckbox = (event, row) => {
      setSelectedRows((state) => 
         ({ 
           ...state, 
           selectedRows: { 
             ...state.selectedRows, 
             [row.id]: event.target.checked
           } 
         })
       );
 };
```

the JSX:

```
 <TableBody>
        {expenseTransactions.map((row) => (
          <TableRow key={row.id}>
            <TableCell>
              <Checkbox 
                checked={ selectedRows[row.id] || false } 
                onChange={(event) => handleCheckbox(event, row)} 
              />
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
   </TableBody>
```

Answer (score 0):

to maintain the checked state in a state, store the checked items' names in the array.

```
  const [checkedState, setChekcedState] = useState([]);
  
  const handleChange = (e) =>{
    const {checked, name} = e.target
    if(checked){
      setChekcedState(oldState => ([...oldState, name]))
    }else{
      setChekcedState(oldState => oldState.filter(item => item !== name))
    }
  }
```

as per the comment, ids are the numbers. So,  convert the number into a string.
And when the array is required, convert those strings back to the number.

```
<TableBody>
    {expenseTransactions.map((item) => (
        <TableRow key={item.id}>
            <Checkbox
                onChange={handleChange}
                checked={checkedState.includes(item.id)}
                name={item.id}
            />
        </TableRow>
    ))}
</TableBody>
```

*Converting those string back into numbers*

```
let convertedIntegerArr = checkedState.map(item=>parseInt(item))
```

Here is the working demo
[image: Edit thirsty-sun-d1zy9]

Comment: Thanks for this. One thing, my ids are numbers which is causing this not to work. How would you solve for that? Cheers

Comment: hi! for this one simple and straightforward solution is to convert that number into a string. I'm updating my answer accordingly